# How to write Hive Regex Or Custom Serde to Parse Weather Data format?

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am working with very popular weather data example from  Hadoop the definitive guide.
One Data Row looks like this.

```
0184010010999992015010100004+70933-008667FM-12+000999999V0200401N01701000301CN000100199-00631-00741098801ADDAA106002031AY171021AY231021GF109991999999999999999999MA1999999098681MD1110121+9999MW1731OD139902601999REMSYN07001001 11/01 90417 11063 21074 39868 49880 51012 60021 77373 333 91126=
```

Data Format is :

```
[1-10]   # USAF weather station identifier
[11-15]  # WBAN weather station identifier
[16-23] # observation date
```

and so on...

Dataset Reference From 
URL : http://ce.sysu.edu.cn/hope/UploadFiles/Education/2011/10/201110221516245419.pdf
Page : 39

Now i have two options

**1.)** To go for RegexSeDe which will take digits out of first token like, 0-5 represents station id 6-12 represnts date and so on... can you help me to write a regex for that ?

**2.)** To go for customSerDe where i can process row for tokens and load the data in hive. I have implemented the SerDe Interface and tried to write a customserDe.But i am getting this exception.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: com.alind.project.hivedatamanager.core.WeatherDataSerDe
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:314)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:146)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$100(SQLOperation.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1$1.run(SQLOperation.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.doAs(HadoopShimsSecure.java:536)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1.run(SQLOperation.java:208)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Cannot validate serde: com.alind.project.hivedatamanager.core.WeatherDataSerDe
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.validateSerDe(DDLTask.java:3722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:999)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:144)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.alind.project.hivedatamanager.core.WeatherDataSerDe not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1980)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.validateSerDe(DDLTask.java:3716)
```

I have already added jar

```
ADD JAR /path-to/MyCustomSerde.jar;
```

Both option i am a little stuck, please help me to go through.
I am unable to even find a good documentation to read !

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the example on page 440 in this book:

```
CREATE TABLE stations (usaf STRING, wban STRING, name STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "(\\d{6}) (\\d{5}) (.{29}) .*"
);
```

There is an explanation there as well. 
Hope it helps :)